# How to simulate the click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tau.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="clickButton();">
<div class="ui-page" id="page_webkitui">
    <header class="ui-header">
        <h2 class="ui-title">Webkit UI demos</h2>
    </header>

    <div class="sample">

        <input type="time" id="input_webkitui_hiddentime"
            style="visibility: hidden; width: 50px"></input>
        <div>
            Hidden time:
            <button class="ui-btn" id="button_webkitui_hiddendateopener"
                style="display: block" onclick="alertTime()">Open timepicker</button>
            <span id="webkitui_hiddentime_value"></span>
        </div>
        <script>

        function alertTime() {
            alert("fff");
            var btn = document.getElementById("button_webkitui_hiddendateopener"), 
            itime = document.getElementById("input_webkitui_hiddentime"), 
            val = document.getElementById("webkitui_hiddentime_value");
            btn.click();
            btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                        itime.click();
            });
            itime.addEventListener("change",function(ev) {
                        val.innerText = itime.value;
                    });

            }


        function clickButton() {
                $(function() {
                    document.getElementById('button_webkitui_hiddendateopener').click();
                    //$('#button_webkitui_hiddendateopener').click();
                });
        }

            (function() {
                var page = document.getElementById("page_webkitui");
                page.addEventListener(
                                "pagecreate",
function(ev) {
var btn = document.getElementById("button_webkitui_hiddendateopener"), 
itime = document.getElementById("input_webkitui_hiddentime"), 
val = document.getElementById("webkitui_hiddentime_value");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                        itime.click();
            });
    itime.addEventListener("change",function(ev) {
                        val.innerText = itime.value;
                    });
                                });
            }());
        </script>

    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tau.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to "force" the **button_webkitui_hiddendateopener** button to be clicked once my page is loaded... (a timepicker is shown normally as a new window).

I implement two functions clickButton() and alertTime(), as a result: only the ffff alert is shown but the new window of the timepicker didn't show up.

What's wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: try getting the button with `$("#button_webkitui_hiddendateopener");` instead and then invoking the click via `btn.trigger('click');` - The answer is a bit longer...

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#button_webkitui_hiddendateopener').trigger("click");
});
```

- Use trigger http://api.jquery.com/trigger/
- **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEttG/)**